# Is it possible to turn on ABAC mode (authorization) in Google Container Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to enable the [ABAC mode](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/authorization.html) for the Kubernetes Cluster I'm using in Google's Container Engine. (more specifically, I would like to restrict access to the API service for the *default* service account which is automatically assigned to all pods). However, since `--authorization-mode=ABAC` is a command line argument for `kube-apiserver` and since the API server is managed in Google Container Engine, I didn't find a way to enable authorization for my cluster.

Is there a way to enable ABAC mode on GCE?

I'm currently running Kubernetes v1.1.7 on server and nodes.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way to enable ABAC mode on Google Container Engine. If you need fine-grained control over the parameters passed to any of the master components you have to run Kubernetes on GCE instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime Google has added the possibility to use Role Based Access Control (RBAC) for a Kubernetes Cluster. It is enabled by default for all new Clusters running Kubernetes 1.6 or later: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/role-based-access-control